# TypeError: Class constructor model cannot be invoked without 'new'

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, sequelize.js, babeljs

I'm using **Sequelize** together with **Node** and **JavaScript** in one app. As you know when you execute `sequelize-init` it creates *config*, *migrations*, *models* and *seeders* folder. Inside of the *models* folder, there is an `index.js` file (generated by the cli), which is responsible for reading all of the models and their associations from the current folder:

index.js

```
'use strict';

const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');
const basename = path.basename(__filename);
const sequelize = require('../database/connection');
const db = {};

fs
  .readdirSync(__dirname)
  .filter(file => {
    return (file.indexOf('.') !== 0) && (file !== basename) && (file.slice(-3) === '.js');
  })
  .forEach(file => {
    const model = require(path.join(__dirname, file))(sequelize, Sequelize.DataTypes);
    db[model.name] = model;
  });

Object.keys(db).forEach(modelName => {
  if (db[modelName].associate) {
    db[modelName].associate(db);
  }
});

db.sequelize = sequelize;
db.Sequelize = Sequelize;

module.exports = db;
```

When I run my app, an error appears: **TypeError: Class constructor model cannot be invoked without 'new'** at line 17 which is the statement: **var model = require(path.join(__dirname, file))(sequelize, Sequelize.DataTypes);** Reading some of the [posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51860043/javascript-es6-typeerror-class-constructor-client-cannot-be-invoked-without-ne) related to this problem I found out that I need to install the `@babel/preset-env` package along with `@babel/cli, @babel/core, @babel/node`. I also created a `.babelrc` file in the root directory, containing the following code:

.babelrc

```
{
    "presets": [
      [
        "@babel/preset-env",
        {
          "targets": {
            "esmodules": true
          }
        }
      ]
    ]
}
```

and updated my `start` option of the `scripts` tag inside `package.json` to: `"nodemon --exec babel-node app.js"` (I don't use webpack)

But when I run the app the error still appears. What do I miss or haven't set correctly?

Comment: You don't need to install babel for a node.js program! You just need to use new instead of calling a class as a function (just like the error is telling you): `const ThingThatIsAClass = require(path.join(__dirname, file)); const model = new ThingThatIsAClass(sequelize, Sequelize.DataTypes);` Don't try to cram so much on to a single line of code. It's hard to read, and makes it easy to miss trivial mistakes like this one.

Comment: I apologize for my incompetence, I didn't know that. I understood that the error is with the way of invoking the constructor, but never though to split the statement. Thank you!

Comment: You don't have to split the statement, you can also write `new (require(…))(…)` but that's even harder to understand.

Comment: @CodiClone no apology needed, programming is hard and inexperience is not a moral failing :)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Note: Check the Why section in the end! If you want to know.

### Problem

The problem is **ES6 classes => are not transpilled with there full features to ES5! Sequelize is relying on some features**

Or

Using `Sequelize.import` in place of require! Don't! (Babel or any transpiler works with require (or es import) and how sequelize.import work is causing problem!)!

### Answer

I guess you are using

```
export class Course extends Model {} // <== ES6 classes

Course.init({
```

Your babel configuration is what's causing that!

You can check that on this github thread [comment](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/7840#issuecomment-315576088)

This worked for the guy

```json
{
  "presets": [
    ["env", {
      "targets": {
        "node": "current"
      }
    }]
  ]
}
```

Or

```json
{
  "presets": [
    [
      "@babel/preset-env",
      {
        "targets": {
          "node": true
        }
      }
    ]
  ]
}
```

[comment](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/7840#issuecomment-471250610)

Making babel use ES6 classes!

Note that **if in the other hand** you just **stick with** `sequelize.define()` way

```
export const User = sequelize.define('User', {
  // Model attributes are defined here
  firstName: {
    type: DataTypes.STRING,
    allowNull: false
  },
```

It will work just right in ES5!

#### Don't use Sequelize.import to import Models

If you are doing then don't! Use `require` or es `import`! The transpiler doesn't handle Sequelize.import directly! And it seems to cause problem

[Comment](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/7840#issuecomment-630709579) showing that

For me it was because of ES6 with Typescript

### Typescript

Default target was `ES5`!

Change that to **ES6+**! And all start working!

For example

```json
"target": "ES2021",
```

#### ES5 with sequelize.define works

Know that ES5 with sequelize.define works just fine!

[image]

#### ES5 with Class extends doesn't work

[image]

#### Illustration

[image]

#### ES6+ works always

[image]

[image]

## Why! Babel doesn't normally transpile right!! ???

You can see that in this github [comment](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/7840#issuecomment-329532407)

> It turns out that an ES6-class transpiled by babel can't extend a real ES6 class (The Sequelize.Model ES6-class for example).
> So class MyEntity extends Sequelize.Model { ... } won't work if MyEntity is transpiled into ES5.

And here the stackoverflow answer explaining better:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/36657312/7668448

> Due to the way ES6 classes work, you cannot extend a native class with a transpiled class. If your platform supports native classes

You can see more depth elements about the why and how possibly such a `transpilation of ES6 Class to ES5 can be done to support full features and compatiblity`! in the links bellow:

https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/17088

https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/15397

And here an article ([comparing-different-ways-of-transpiling-es6-class-to-es5](https://medium.com/@huozhi/comparing-different-ways-of-transpiling-es6-class-to-es5-95f7d9ccefa2)) that go in more details about the subject

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation!

Answer (score 0):

If you have "es5" in "target" in tsconfig.json file, changes to "es6". (that worked for me, and I needed the es6 in compiler.)

```
"compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es6"
}
```